# Read Content From Word Document In C# With Out Use Word Dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

hiii

i want to get content from Microsoft word file with out
Microsoft.Office.Interop dll uses.

I also use this code but its only read text from  .xml file and .txt file not in .doc file

```
using System.IO;
using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath)) { string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();  }
```

Comment: what is the file's extension? doc or docx?

Comment: one way or another, you would need a 3rd party DLL to read MS Word files if you don't want to use the interop approach

Comment: Aspose has a decent fully-managed library around this, if you can afford it.

Answer (score 2):

office documents are more complex than simple xml/txt files since they contain much more text-related information (fonts, colors, locations, tables, images, etc etc).

Starting from Office 2007, microsoft uses the 'Office Open XML' format for saving office files. To parse a docx file, rename its extension to zip (e.g. untitled1.docx.zip) and extract its contents (using any zip app/library).

You will get a few files and folders, navigate to the 'word' folder and simply read the file named 'document.xml'.

This file contains all the textual information of the document (it is xml-formatted, so be sure to parse it correctly).

If you want to extract textual information of a pre-2007 files (e.g. 'doc' file), you will have to use [Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3), which migrates files to the new format (it can be used programmatically, read about it)

Answer (score 1):

Add the Namespace using Add Reference-->Browse-->Code7248.word_reader.dll.

Download the dll from the given URL :

[sourceforge.net/p/word-reader/wiki/Home/](http://sourceforge.net/p/word-reader/wiki/Home/)

(A simple .NET Library compatible with .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0 for C#. It can currently extract only the raw text from a .doc or .docx file.)

The Sample Code is in simple Console in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
//add extra namespaces
using Code7248.word_reader;


namespace testWordRead
{
    class Program
    {
        private void readFileContent(string path)
        {
            TextExtractor extractor = new TextExtractor(path);
            string text = extractor.ExtractText();
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program cs = new Program();
            string path = "D:\Test\testdoc1.docx";
            cs.readFileContent(path);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It's working fine with doc & docx formet files.