# Print Word document from Asp.net c# Without MS Office Installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I need to print Word document without installing MS Office.
I am using WordprocessingDocument to manipulate Word file.

Now I need to print it.

I have tried:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process printProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
printProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "D:/testWordPad1.docx";
printProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
printProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
printProcess.Start();
printProcess.WaitForExit();
```

It works in my local system which has MS Office installed. **But it does not work at my server which does not have MS office installed.**

It shows me:

> No application is associated with the specified file for this operation -    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

Please give me your suggestions regarding this.

Comment: According to your example, you pass a text file as the process name [which, on your server, probably calls the 'notepad' application]. are you sure you want to print word document?

Comment: The `.txt` extension has nothing to do with Microsoft Word. Notepad should be able to print it, for example.

Comment: Sorry its my printing mistake. Actually I am using .docx file in my code here.

Comment: You have to use Aspose or similar products in order to _reliable_ work with office documents on a web server.

Comment: Hi Uwe Keim, Can you please tell me that Is it required to have installation of MS Office on server for this?

Comment: Are you trying to send a document to clients printer from a web-site? The tags suggest you are executing a print job through a web-site.

Comment: Yes client should print document from my web site i.e. .OXPS file

Answer (score 0):

In order to print textual files [which is what it seems you try to do], you can use notepad's command line arguments [read more [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/notepadexe-command-line-options/810760c1-a45a-4013-9544-1c1208e1b389?auth=1)]

The following will send the document to the default printer:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process printProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                printProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
                printProcess.StartInfo.Parameters = "/P D:\\testWordPad1.txt";
                printProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                printProcess.Start();
                printProcess.WaitForExit();
```

If you want to define the printer to which the file will be sent, use the following parameter:

/PT [filename] [printername] [driverdll] [port]

Comment: Thanks Nissim, It works for .txt file. But it was my printing mistake. Actually its .docx file in my code.

Comment: Well, docx files are basically in open-xml format. you can change the file's extension to '.zip' to extract graphical and textual information from the file. You. Please refer to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30860116/120391

Answer (score 0):

The Error means, that the Verb is not available.
First you can check the available Verbs like this:

```
    foreach (String verb in printProcess.StartInfo.Verbs)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(verb);
    }
```

Are you sure that there any printing facilities available on your Server?
If you do a right click on that file on your server, does it show "Print" in the context menu?

Comment: Thanks Bgl86, I am getting "Print" as verb in this loop. And my server has Notepad but not MS Office. I am not sure that this problem is due to No MS Office installation.

Comment: And i am getting this error when control reached at printProcess.Start()

Answer (score 0):

To print .docx files on web server without MS Office installed, a third party library might be the best choice. I tried [a free component](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.Doc/) (nuget package) with 100 passages and 5 tables limits for small project and it works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Spire.Doc;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Printing;


namespace Doc_Print
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Document doc = new Document(); 
            doc.LoadFromFile("sample.doc");
            PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
            dialog.AllowPrintToFile = true; 
            dialog.AllowCurrentPage = true;
            dialog.AllowSomePages = true;
            dialog.UseEXDialog = true; 
            doc.PrintDialog = dialog;               
            PrintDocument printDoc = doc.PrintDocument; 
            printDoc.Print();
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {               
                printDoc.Print();
            }            

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this on windows apps and got it works fine, @NOW I need same thing for asp.net web apps, can I???